# How to compute the convolution of two unequal length vectors

Tags: fft

I know  the convolution can computed with FFT.
 `F*H = IDFT[DFT(F)DFT(H)]`. * means convolution.

what if the length of F and H is unequal. then the  length of DFT(H) and DFT(F) is unequal. **so how to compute the element-wise multiply between two unequal length vectors.**  Did I forget something?

Comment: The relation you provided is for circular convolution. Do you really wish to obtain circular convolution of unequal length vectors, or do you want the more usual linear convolution? In the latter case, the issue with the length is solved by padding the vectors to the same length (note also that you'd have to pad the vectors to get the linear convolution in the first place).

Comment: @SleuthEye how to pad the vector in the two case that you mentioed. And what's the differences

Comment: For the difference you could check [discrete circular convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Circular_discrete_convolution) and [discrete (linear) convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution). For padding in the linear convolution case, you'd zero pad to a length `N+M-1` where `N` & `M` are the length of `F` and `H`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do a linear fast convolution of two vectors of length H and F, one normally zero-pads both to the same length, a length of at least H+F-1 or longer, possibly to the next greater length that is the product of very small prime factors (such as 2^n).

Any shorter length than H+F-1 results in a circular convolution, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: After  IDFT of the (H+F-1) length of the result.  What's the length of should I use

Comment: The expected length of any convolution result.